# Heroku app page won't display after making a new commit, even though there are no errors in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a Hacker News clone hosted on Heroku and I cloned it to make a change so that the votes can be sorted by date, as well as, by vote count. That went well and I then tested with rspec making sure I  was all green. Lastly, I pushed to Heroku which also went fine with no errors being reported.

However, when I visited the url, it says "We're sorry, but something went wrong.". Normally, I would troubleshoot but there is no message in the deployment or rspec so I am not sure what do do? If anyone has encountered this or can suggest something for me to try I'd appreciate that. Here is my terminal output after running rspec and deploying :

```
Finished in 0.60271 seconds
11 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 33033

jasonrodriguez:infinite-castle-2099 jasonrodriguez$ git add . -A
jasonrodriguez:infinite-castle-2099 jasonrodriguez$ git commit -m "verifying that this app is committed"
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
jasonrodriguez:infinite-castle-2099 jasonrodriguez$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date
jasonrodriguez:infinite-castle-2099 jasonrodriguez$
```

I did this through the master branch `jasonrodriguez:infinite-castle-2099 jasonrodriguez$ git branch
* master`

I ran `heroku logs --tail` and it gave me this :

```
jasonrodriguez:infinite-castle-2099 jasonrodriguez$ heroku logs --tail
2013-10-19T17:03:32.558564+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...8695' AND '2013-10-19 17:03:32.548861')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:03:32.558717+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </thead>
2013-10-19T17:03:32.558717+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <% Link.most_voted.each do |link| %>
2013-10-19T17:03:32.558717+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:     </tr>
2013-10-19T17:03:32.558717+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:03:33.819411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=infinite-castle-2099.herokuapp.com fwd="67.170.184.10" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:24:26.163272+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.170.184.10 at 2013-10-19 17:24:26 +0000
2013-10-19T17:24:26.163272+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.170.184.10 at 2013-10-19 17:24:26 +0000
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...4736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:24:26.164736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:24:26.164736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:24:26.168406+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:24:26.175677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-castle-2099.herokuapp.com fwd="67.170.184.10" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-10-19T17:24:26.164068+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LinksController#index as HTML
2013-10-19T17:24:26.164068+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LinksController#index as HTML
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <tbody class="stories">
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:24:26.164736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100):
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:                    <%= f.submit  '▲' %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:24:26.168250+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered links/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/links/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_links_index_html_erb___4309851234159801657_70037839513200'
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:           <%= form_for link.votes.new do |f| %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:           <%= form_for link.votes.new do |f| %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...4736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <% Link.most_voted.each do |link| %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:     </tr>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/links/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_links_index_html_erb___4309851234159801657_70037839513200'
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:     </tr>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:                    <%= f.hidden_field :link_id %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <tbody class="stories">
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </thead>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.167584+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...4736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:24:26.168489+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...4736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:                    <%= f.submit  '▲' %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.168250+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered links/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </thead>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:24:26.164736' AND '2013-10-19 17:24:26.164831')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100):
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170324+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <% Link.most_voted.each do |link| %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170479+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:                    <%= f.hidden_field :link_id %>
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:24:26.170626+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:25:15.524381+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.90.16.79 at 2013-10-19 17:25:15 +0000
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529687+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered links/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:25:15.525998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100
2013-10-19T17:25:15.524381+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 99.90.16.79 at 2013-10-19 17:25:15 +0000
2013-10-19T17:25:15.525289+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LinksController#index as HTML
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:25:15.525289+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LinksController#index as HTML
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...5998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...5998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:25:15.525998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100):
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529798+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </thead>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:     </tr>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529687+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered links/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529083+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:25:15.525998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <tbody class="stories">
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE ("links"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-10-12 17:25:15.525998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_count DESC LIMIT 100):
2013-10-19T17:25:15.529798+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <tbody class="stories">
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...5998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   </thead>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "votes_count" does not exist
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...5998' AND '2013-10-19 17:25:15.526107')  ORDER BY votes_coun...
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <% Link.most_voted.each do |link| %>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/links/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_links_index_html_erb___4309851234159801657_70037839513200'
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:                    <%= f.hidden_field :link_id %>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:           <%= form_for link.votes.new do |f| %>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:                    <%= f.submit  '▲' %>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <% Link.most_voted.each do |link| %>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/links/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_links_index_html_erb___4309851234159801657_70037839513200'
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:           <%= form_for link.votes.new do |f| %>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531524+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:     </tr>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:                    <%= f.submit  '▲' %>
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531695+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-10-19T17:25:15.531841+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:                    <%= f.hidden_field :link_id %>
2013-10-19T17:25:16.054820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=infinite-castle-2099.herokuapp.com fwd="99.90.16.79" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-10-19T17:25:15.537591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=infinite-castle-2099.herokuapp.com fwd="99.90.16.79" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=1266
```

Apparently, it says it cannot find `votes_count` even though it is right here in my schema.rb :

```
  create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "votes_count"
  end
```

Comment: check your heroku logs.  the problem seems to be specific to the prod env.  set `config.consider_all_requests_local` in your production.rb to true, this will show the error log instead of the default heroku error message

Comment: Thanks for that tip, super helpful! I now have a breadcrumb trail!

Comment: So, it tells me the same thing as `heroku logs --tail` in that, it cannot find my `votes_count` column even though it is in in my `schema.rb`. I have edited my post to show my schema.

Comment: did you run your migrations on heroku?

Comment: I just did and that worked, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I visited the url, it says "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

run in your terminal

```
heroku logs --tail
```

to analyze logs you can also refresh page to see latest logs. Please try to find error and paste it here so we can help you more

Edit

try to run your migrations on heroku

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find a command like that. I pulled it up and apparently it says the `votes_count` column is not there but it is showing up in my `schema.rb`. Do I need to create a db locally and be sure to have that column before pushing to Heroku?

Comment: @user2726874 just try to run your migrations. You will find command in my updated answer

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot for your help. The problem is that when I ran my migration, I did not put the heroku keyword in front : /